# Removed .php extension but now it says page does not exist

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

I was able to get the .php off my files but now when I go to the pages they do not exist(and it's forcing a WordPress 404 page when the target files are actually on the server outside of WordPress).  I think the problem might be that it's on a server with WordPress and these files lie outside of word press.  There's already rewrite rules for WordPress and maybe it's conflicting with my rewrite rules for other files?

.htaccess file:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress

# Remove .php extension on files outside of wordPress
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ /[^?\s]+\.php
RewriteRule (.*)\.php$ /$1/ [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(.+)/$
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%1.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ $1.php [L]

# Force trailing slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule .*[^/]$ $0/ [L,R=301]
```

UPDATE - Full .htaccess

```
# BEGIN WP Hide & Security Enhancer
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c> 
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteBase / 
#WriteCheckString:1548706048_68906
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_MOD_REWRITE:On]

RewriteRule ^site(.*) /wp-login.php$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteRule ^wp-login.php /index.php?wph-throw-404 [L]


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /enter$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /enter/ [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^enter(.*) /wp-admin$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteRule ^wp-admin(.+) /index.php?wph-throw-404 [L]

</IfModule> 

# END WP Hide & Security Enhancer




# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Comment: What happens is once you do the redirect `(.*)\.php$ /$1/ [L,R=301]` the request happens again but with no extension then this is true `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f && RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d` which makes the `RewriteRule . /index.php [L]` (last wordpress redirect) trigger on that redirected request.  Because of the `[L]` last flag that ends Mod Rewrites involvement and your later rules never run on the second request.

Comment: Interesting and I mostly understand.  Any idea how to remedy this?

Comment: Change the order of the re-write rules, so wordpress happens last.  Then you can check what you need to and either handle the request or allow wordpress to take it.

Comment: Just to further explain.  `RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]` if start and ends with `index.php`, this basically just ends Mod Rewrite (because of the `[L]` if the request is to `index.php`)..  `%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` if not file, and `%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d` if not directory then turn `.` everything into `index.php` and end `[L]`.  On the first pass wordpress ignores it because `somefile.php` is a file.  Then when the redirect happens you have `somefile`  and the request starts over from the top of HTACCESS.  But now because `somefile` is not a known file or folder wordpress catches it.

Comment: Interesting.  I changed the order and now it's not going to an error page but the page is just stuck on loading.  And if I stop the page from loading it and it renders but with no css?

Comment: It will take more then just moving some stuff around.

Comment: Anything I do it wont work.  I updated the question to add the whole htaccess.  you think this security feature we added can be messing with what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do something like this

```
#remove all PHP extensions from the url
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ /[^?\s]+\.php
RewriteRule (.*)\.php$ /$1/ [L,R=301] #end and redirect


# Force trailing slash ( probably no longer needed, because `/$1/` )
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
#RewriteRule .*[^/]$ $0/ [L,R=301]

#add .php back in and continue.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(.+)/$
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%1.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ $1.php  #no last flag as we can now continue to WP with our nice php extensions back on

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

I'm assuming those rewrite rules are correct.  I would have to look them up I haven't worked heavily with Rewrites in a few years.  Basically

- first remove any php extensions and redirect (if they exist)
- on a redirect (or a request without .php) add back the php extension to those urls where it was removed so you may need `%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d` just to be safe.
- carry on as normal

Just as a general rule of thumb, it's best to do redirects first.  That way you can get to the redirect with the shortest amount of work.  A redirect is like changing the url and then putting that in the browser and running it again (ie. a brand new request).

Another way to do this is to redirect all requests to a certain folder to an index.php of your making that has a router.

Such as this one (that I made as an example)

https://github.com/ArtisticPhoenix/MISC/tree/master/Router

Then your URL's can be like this

```
http://yourdomain.com/somedir/index.php/controller/method/...args
#or without the index.php
http://yourdomain.com/somedir/controller/method/...args
```

Then in HTACCESS all you would do is remove index.php

```
 #remove index.php and redirect
 RewriteRule somedir/index.php/(.+)/?$ /somedir/$1/ [L,R=301] #end and

 #add index.php back in
 RewriteRule somedir/(.+)/?$ /somedir/index.php/$1/ [L] 

 //wordpress stuff
```

The nice thing about routers is you never have to touch Htaccess, and with a folder name to key in on it should make things simpler.

Using the router and the example files:

```
 http://yourdomain.com/somedir/user/login
```

Should go to `Controllers/user.php` method `login`.

Comment: Shouldn't you have an <ifModule mod_rewrite.c> on the other code too, technically?

Comment: I put this in but it blocks me from the server when I do.  Am I missing any tags or anything?   Like <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

Comment: beat me to it @Chipster   I just don't don't know if I should put them around all the top part of section them each individually.  Also I'll need to call RewriteEngine On again right?

Comment: Well, I'm sure Artistic Pheonix has a better answer, but in my opinion you could just add it around the new code and leave wordpress' code alone.

Comment: `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>` this just prevents problems on servers without `mod_rewrite`  HTACCESS is used for more then just re-writing.  In other words it's not really necessary for testing.

Comment: So I tried putting tags around them and it's still doing the loading thing forever.  I need to sign off for a while now but I'll give you the answer if we can figure it out of the comments. thanks

Comment: Your probably stuck in a redirect loop.  My guess would be the last rule I omitted `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f` and  `RewriteRule .*[^/]$ $0/ [L,R=301]` is redirecting. Because at that point it would have the `.php` extension.  I omitted it because I don't think it's needed anymore (Maybe).

Comment: Anything I do it wont work.  I updated the question to add the whole htaccess.  you think this security feature we added can be messing with what I'm trying to do?

Comment: Finally figured it out.  Was actually working I just didn't realize I need to change all the links to those pages and take out the file extension.  So gave it to you,  thanks for the help last week!

Comment: That would indicate that this condition `RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ /[^?\s]+\.php`  fails and this `RewriteRule (.*)\.php$ /$1/ [L,R=301]` never happens, This RewriteCond  I just copied from what you had as I don't know what your requirements are.  For example I could simply remove all `.php` and it would be a fine answer but I don't know if that would actually work on your setup.

Comment: See when you have the `.php` in the url then this rule `RewriteRule (.*)\.php$ /$1/ [L,R=301]` should redirect you after removing the `.php`.  Then that condition should fail on the new request (redirect) as the extension is now missing (because we removed it above) and then the new request (from the redirect) will work as if you had not had `.php` it the original URL.  You can test this by removing that condition ( or comment it with `#` ) and do that url with `.php`

Comment: That said, typically you want to remove the extension if possible as it saves you the time it takes to do the redirect and fix the url.  See to change a url "in the users browser" you must redirect, but to change the url on the server you just change it.  So basically that first redirect just makes the URL look nice for the user, then on the request after the redirect ( the second request ) we "magically" add the extension back in for the "server" so it can find it.  IN addition changing that for every url with .php would cause redirects in wordpress's back end. `login.php` etc.